# Check if at least one checkbox is checked without clicking

Tags: jquery

How to check without clicking on the buttons that at least one of selected checkboxes on the page is checked ? Thanks!

```
<script>
$('#filter').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each( function(){


   if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked")){
     $('#status').text("yes");
   }
   else {
   $('#status').text("no");
   }

});
</script>

 <div id="filter">
<input id='id1' type='checkbox' />
<input id='id1' type='checkbox' />
<input id='id1' type='checkbox' />


</div>

<label id='status' />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all remove the # from the div id in HTML.

Also consider making checkbox ids unique.

And to check whether any checkbox is checked, you can get by following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function updateStatus(){
 if ($('div#filter input:checked').length > 0 ){
    $('#status').text("yes");
 }
 else {
    $('#status').text("no");
 } 
}

$('div#filter input[type="checkbox"]').on("change",updateStatus); 
updateStatus(); 
});
```

Not aware about your use case but you can also check it by calling the function after every 1 second (or as per requirement) like below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function updateStatus(){
 if ($('div#filter input:checked').length > 0 ){
    $('#status').text("yes");
 }
 else {
    $('#status').text("no");
 } 
}

window.setInterval(updateStatus, 1000); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

by using `.length`

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length !== 0
```

Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#filter input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length !== 0){
      alert('one or more checked');
    }else{
      alert('Nothing checked');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filter">
  <input id='id1' type='checkbox' />
  <input id='id1' type='checkbox' />
  <input id='id1' type='checkbox' />
</div>
```